# C# atom reference type equivalent to clojure atom

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, clojure, atomic

Is there a C# BCL equivalent to Clojure atom, something like `Atom<T>` that provides atomic swap/reset semantics for reference type T ? .NET has immutable collections so so I could see using this class just like in Clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# has the `Interlocked` class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx

you can do swaps with `Interlocked.CompareExchange` generically:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Interlocked can be used to implement atom but clojure atom is higher level - swap function takes a lambda and does a compareexchange with the result, if it fails it retries with new atom state (up to specified times). But I guess this is the closes you can get in BCL so the answer to my question is no.